# Is there a way to get Tomcat 7 to display the servlet mappings?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I'm getting a 404 from Tomcat for a very simple web app.  I'm currently thinking the problem is the servlet mapping because there are no errors in any of the Tomcat logs.

Is there a way to get Tomcat to display the active servlet mappings?  I thought the manager console might do this but when I click on the mapping for my app I also get a 404.  So either this is not the way to do it or there is something else wrong that is not being logged.

Thanks for any help or advice,
beeky

Comment: Can you add your current web.xml to your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display them via `servletContext.getServletRegistrations()` - you have all the metadata available there. You can do that in a `ServletContextListener`, to print all data as soon as the context is loaded.

Comment: Just a hint: this method is available starting from Servlets 3.0. You cannot use it on Google App Engine because it utilizes version 2.5.

Comment: Why would I want this inside my code? Why isn't a simple option in Tomcat to display all the URLs?